# Search for forbidden words in string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I would like to detect a vulgar word in a string. I have a database of indecent words stored in `.txt` file. This file I put into my `.py` file.

Example bad word:

```
words = "word, something, dog, cat ...."
```

input data string are for example:

```
input = "xxxxdogxxx" or "dogxxxx" or "xxxdog" or "dog" "ok_word" # xxx == any word
```

and I want, when input contains the word in word return is False

```
def check(input):
    word = "something, something, ..."
    x = ???? # I do not know how to do it, probably using regular expressions: re.match?
    if x:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: i think you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: do you know how to split a string in to an array of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not need Regex for this.  You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
def check(input):
    return all(x not in input for x in bad_words)
```

To make your string of words into a list, use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> words = "word, something, dog, cat"
>>> words.split(', ')
['word', 'something', 'dog', 'cat']
>>>
```

You might also want to call `set()` on the list to improve lookup times.  Sets have `O(1)` (constant) complexity with the `in` and `not in` operators while lists have `O(n)` (linear).  So, it is faster to find things in a set than it is with a list.

Comment: That's what I tried, but my problem was: split (", ") without space. Thanks.